# How to pass key json file while creating SessionsClient in Dialogflow Java API

Tags: java, dialogflow-es

We can pass the key.json file obtained from GCM project as a parameter while creating the SessionsClient in nodejs as below.

```js
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({
    keyFilename: '/path/to/google.json'
});
```

What is the equivalent API in java, or how  we can handle the key file loading programmatically in java ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from these [link](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-java-client-v2/issues/25#issuecomment-432107722).

Used the method `GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);`

Sample java code is given below.

```java
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File("absolute path to /key.json"));
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
String projectId = ((ServiceAccountCredentials)credentials).getProjectId();
SessionsSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = SessionsSettings.newBuilder();
SessionsSettings sessionsSettings = settingsBuilder.setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)).build();

SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create(sessionsSettings);
String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
SessionName session = SessionName.of(projectId, sessionId);
```

Add the below dependencies in gradle file.

```
implementation group: 'com.google.api', name: 'gax', version: '1.5.0'
implementation group: 'com.google.cloud', name: 'google-cloud-dialogflow', version: '2.0.0'
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-core', version: '1.30.0'
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-api', version: '1.30.0'
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-okhttp', version: '1.30.0'
```